# Removing given value from list and storing in accumulator

Tags: list, debugging, prolog, accumulator

So far I have:

```
remove(_,[],R,R).

remove(X,[H|T],[],R) :- X =\= H, remove(X,T,[_|H],R).
```

But I can't quite work out why it's not working. The first is the base case when the list has been exhausted, and the accumulator is copied to R.

The second defines that the head must not equal X, and then recurse into the tail and add the Head to the accumulator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, `=\=` is disequality of the values of arithmetic expressions. It is not a general "unequal" predicate. For example, this doesn't work well:

```
?- a =\= b.
ERROR: =\=/2: Arithmetic: `a/0' is not a function
```

So your predicate has no hope of working for anything that is not a list of numbers or other arithmetic expressions. If your Prolog system has `dif/2`, use that:

```
?- dif(a, b).
true.
```

Only if the above doesn't work, use `\=` for disequality:

```
?- a \= b.
true.
```

(The difference between these two is that `dif` handles variables correctly, while `\=` doesn't.)

Now, one immediate problem in your code is that you pattern match a list as `[H|T]`, then try to construct a new list `[_|H]` for the recursive call. This raises a red flag: if `H` is the *head* of the first list, then in general it will not be a list itself. But non-lists should not appear as the *tail* in the list constructor. For example, if we match the list `[1, 2, 3]`:

```
?- [H|T] = [1, 2, 3].
H = 1,
T = [2, 3].
```

... and then try to construct a new list with this `H` as its tail:

```
?- [H|T] = [1, 2, 3], Xs = [42 | H].
H = 1,
T = [2, 3],
Xs = [42|1].
```

... the result will not be a list:

```
?- [H|T] = [1, 2, 3], Xs = [42 | H], is_list(Xs).
false.
```

You probably want to have `H` as the *head* of the new accumulator, like so:

```
remove(X, [H|T], R0, R) :-
    dif(X, H),
    remove(X, T, [H|R0], R).
```

Another thing I changed from your second clause is that the accumulator `R0` is not required to be `[]`, as in your definition. In your definition, the recursive call would fail immediately since the new, non-empty accumulator would not unify with `[]`.

This already works for some cases:

```
?- remove(a, [b, c, d], [], Result).
Result = [d, c, b] ;
false.
```

But not for others:

```
?- remove(a, [a], [], Result).
false.
```

You only have two clauses so far: One for the empty list (which doesn't apply here) and another for the case when the element to be removed is not equal to the head of the list (which doesn't apply here either!). You need a third clause for the case where the head of the list is the element to be removed:

```
remove(X, [X|T], R0, R) :-
   ... %  fill in here
```

---

**Edit:** As pointed out in the comments, the solution sketched above reverses the list of elements in the result list. This is usual for accumulator-based recursive list predicates: *later* list elements become *earlier* accumulator elements.

However, an accumulator isn't needed here. The result can be constructed directly. Here is an implementation:

```
remove(_X, [], []).
remove(X, [Y|Xs], [Y|Ys]) :-
    dif(X, Y),
    remove(X, Xs, Ys).
remove(X, [X|Xs], Ys) :-
    remove(X, Xs, Ys).
```

This works for both positive and negative test cases:

```
?- remove(a, [b, a, c], Result).
Result = [b, c] ;
false.

?- remove(a, [b, c, d], Result).
Result = [b, c, d] ;
false.
```

It works in the general case:

```
?- remove(X, Xs, Ys).
Xs = Ys, Ys = [] ;
Xs = Ys, Ys = [_G4794505],
dif(X, _G4794505) ;
Xs = Ys, Ys = [_G4794601, _G4794604],
dif(X, _G4794604),
dif(X, _G4794601) ;
Xs = Ys, Ys = [_G4794697, _G4794700, _G4794703],
dif(X, _G4794703),
dif(X, _G4794700),
dif(X, _G4794697) ;
Xs = Ys, Ys = [_G4794793, _G4794796, _G4794799, _G4794802],
dif(X, _G4794802),
dif(X, _G4794799),
dif(X, _G4794796),
dif(X, _G4794793) ;
Xs = Ys, Ys = [_G4794889, _G4794892, _G4794895, _G4794898, _G4794901],
dif(X, _G4794901),
dif(X, _G4794898),
dif(X, _G4794895),
dif(X, _G4794892),
dif(X, _G4794889) ;
Xs = Ys, Ys = [_G4794985, _G4794988, _G4794991, _G4794994, _G4794997, _G4795000],
dif(X, _G4795000),
dif(X, _G4794997),
dif(X, _G4794994),
dif(X, _G4794991),
dif(X, _G4794988),
dif(X, _G4794985) .
```

But the enumeration above is not fair! It only exercises the second clause, not the third one. We can get fair enumeration by grouping by the length of `Xs`:

```
?- length(Xs, N), remove(X, Xs, Ys).
Xs = Ys, Ys = [],
N = 0 ;
Xs = Ys, Ys = [_G4794582],
N = 1,
dif(X, _G4794582) ;
Xs = [X],
N = 1,
Ys = [] ;
Xs = Ys, Ys = [_G4794678, _G4794681],
N = 2,
dif(X, _G4794678),
dif(X, _G4794681) ;
Xs = [_G4794585, X],
N = 2,
Ys = [_G4794585],
dif(X, _G4794585) ;
Xs = [X, _G4794588],
N = 2,
Ys = [_G4794588],
dif(X, _G4794588) ;
Xs = [X, X],
N = 2,
Ys = [] ;
Xs = Ys, Ys = [_G4794774, _G4794777, _G4794780],
N = 3,
dif(X, _G4794774),
dif(X, _G4794780),
dif(X, _G4794777) .
```

We can also use this "backwards" in a limited way: By leaving the second argument `Xs` free and specifying a concrete list for the third argument `Ys`, we get a predicate *inserting* the given element into `Ys` in all the possible places, giving `Xs`:

```
?- remove(a, Xs, [b, c, d]).
Xs = [b, c, d] ;
Xs = [b, c, d, a] ;
Xs = [b, c, d, a, a] ;
Xs = [b, c, d, a, a, a] .
```

Again this is not fair, but again that can be fixed:

```
?- length(Xs, N), remove(a, Xs, [b, c, d]).
Xs = [b, c, d],
N = 3 ;
Xs = [b, c, d, a],
N = 4 ;
Xs = [b, c, a, d],
N = 4 ;
Xs = [b, a, c, d],
N = 4 ;
Xs = [a, b, c, d],
N = 4 ;
Xs = [b, c, d, a, a],
N = 5 .  % etc.
```

Comment: `(The difference between these two...)` seems not accurate. `\=` it's a standard (ISO) predicate, dif/2 it's an extension supported only on systems having coroutining, hence non standard semantic. But I agree that where supported, better to use it. Maybe after learned how to debug such programs...

Comment: Nice explanation. But why are you reversing the order of the elements in the resulting list (`[d,c,b]` instead of `[b,c,d]`)? Swapping the third argument in the head of your recursive rule with the third argument of the recursive goal would preserve the ordering of the remaining elements. And changing the third argument of the non-recursive rule to `[]` would make the fourth argument unnecessary thus describing the relation with just three arguments.

Comment: Good points. I wanted to stay as close to the code in the question as possible, which was about how to use an accumulator. But you are right that an answer explaining how *not* to use an accumulator would also be useful. If you write it, I'll upvote it!

Comment: I was hoping you might like to incorporate that into your post ;-) After all, you've already made the effort of explaining. And my point was not about _how not to use an accumulator_. If reversing the order of the elements was an objective, your code would be absolutely fine. The OP just did not explicitly ask for that, so why do it? And after reading your explanations my finger is really itching to hit that upvote button, especially since you advertise the use of `dif/2`.

Comment: Well then. Fire away ;-)

Comment: pew pew pew :-D